# Confusion regarding uniform continuity

Tags: functions, derivatives, uniform-continuity

I was trying to check the validity of the following:

If $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ and its derivative $f'$ are unbounded, then $f$ is not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R$.

---

To me,the statement appears to be valid at first sight, but I am not sure. I know that boundedness of $f'$ is sufficient to prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous in its domain. Further, if $f'$ is unbounded, then $f$ may or may not be uniformly continuous. I thought of $f(x)=x^2$ with its derivative $f'(x)=2x$, both of which are unbounded on $\mathbb R$ and supports the statement, but I am not sure whether a counterexample exists. Please, correct me if I am wrong to conclude anything from this statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then answer is no, the statement is not true. Take for example the cube root $x \mapsto x^\frac{1}{3}$. This map is  [uniformly continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/687414/prove-continuity-for-cubic-root-using-epsilon-delta) on $\mathbb{R}$. But its derivative and itself are unbounded.