# Uniform continuity of square root

Tags: continuity

I need to prove that $f(x)=\sqrt x$ is uniformly continuous on $[0, \infty)$.

I wrote $\displaystyle |\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{c}|=|\frac{(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{c})(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{c})}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{c}}| \leq| \frac{x-c}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{c}}|$, but I am stuck after this. I found a solution that takes $\delta = \epsilon^2$, but I don't understand where this comes from. If we take this $\delta$, we will get the necessary result, but it seems like we are assuming $\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{c}=\epsilon$ rather than showing it.

Can someone explain the confusion or suggest another epsilon-delta solution?

Comment: Note: $\left|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{c}\right| = \left|\dfrac{(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{c})(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{c})}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{c}}\right| = \left|\dfrac{x-c}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{c}}\right|$, rather than inequality.

Comment: Hmm, it appears that someone edited my post incorrectly, and removed the expression I intended. I had that $\frac{(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{c})(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{c})}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{c}} = \frac{x-c}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{c}} \leq \frac{x-c}{\sqrt{x} MINUS \sqrt{c}}$

Comment: [Duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569928/sqrt-x-is-uniformly-continuous)

Comment: I saw that question, but I did not understand the answers.

Comment: Alternatively: Since $x^{1/2}$ is clearly continuous then is uniform continuous on $[0,1]$. Now we will show that also is uniform continuous on $[1, \infty)$. 

Let $(a_n)_{n=0}^\infty,\,(b_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ be two sequences such that $a_n-b_n \rightarrow 0$ and $a_n,b_n \in [1,\infty)$. Then we'd like to show that $(a_n)^{1/2}-(b_n)^{1/2} \rightarrow 0$. 


$$|a^{1/2}-b^{1/2}|= \bigg|\frac{a_n-b_n}{a^{1/2}+b^{1/2}}\bigg|\le |a_n-b_n|/2$$

Since $a_n,b_n\ge 1 $ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then  since $(a_n-b_n)\rightarrow 0$, we're done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** Prove the inequality $|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}|\le \sqrt{|x-y|}$.

Comment: Hmm, could you give more hints on how to do this?

Comment: @kiwifruit square both sides of this inequality.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to prove this, but at what part does this come in in the epsilon-delta proof?

Comment: @kiwifruit now suppose that $|x-y| < \epsilon^2$, what can we say about $\sqrt{|x-y|}$?

Answer (score 1):

Just divide it into two parts. On $[0,1]$ there is Heine–Cantor theorem. And on $[1, \infty)$ the denominator is greater (or equal) than 2.

Comment: Thank you, but this theorem was not covered in class.Could you elaborate why the denominator greater than two is important?

Comment: What denominator? I think you were thinking of the derivative...

Comment: I'm referring to "denominator is greater (or equal) than 2"

Comment: $|\sqrt x - \sqrt y| = \left|\frac{x-y}{\sqrt x +\sqrt y}\right|\leq\frac 12 |x - y|<\frac 12 \delta$

Comment: Oh, ok, that makes sense for $[1, \infty]$, but is there another more basic theorem that can be used for [0,1]?

Comment: More basic (at this stage) than the H-C theorem, @kiwifruit? I highly doubt it, and any try in this direction would probably be equivalent to a pretty close form of this theorem and/or its proof.