# Uniform continuity problem

Tags: calculus, continuity

Let $f(x)$ be continuous on $[0, \infty)$, $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$ be continuous on $(0, \infty)$. Which of the following statements are true:

I. If $f'(x) > 0$ and $f''(x) < 0$, then f(x) is uniformly continuous on $[0, \infty)$

II. If $f'(x) < 0$ and $f''(x) > 0$, then f(x) is uniformly continuous on $[0, \infty)$

III. If $f'(x) < 0$ and $f''(x) < 0$, then f(x) is uniformly continuous on $[0, \infty)$

I think that I and III are false.

Counterexample for I: $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$

Counterexample for III: $f(x) = -x^2$

EDIT: I deleted my "counterexample" for II because it was a mistake. So, my question is how to prove/disprove II?

Comment: Wouldn't $-\sqrt{x}$ work for II just as it worked for I?

Comment: I think that it does.

Comment: @DavidMitra, yes, I've already deleted it.

Comment: [$f(x)=\sqrt x$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569928/sqrt-x-is-uniformly-continuous). You can adapt the argument in the first answer there to show I is true (and then II is true by considering $-f$).

Answer (score 1):

Note I and II are equivalent since you can go from one to the other by replacing $f$ by $-f$.

Focusing on I, it suffices to show uniform continuity on $[1,\infty)$ since just by continuity $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$. If $y > x \geq 1$, then by the mean value
theorem 
$$f(y) - f(x) = f'(z)(y - x)$$
Here $z$ is between $x$ and $y$. Since $f'' < 0$, you have $f'(z) < f'(1)$. So
$$f(y) - f(x) < f'(1)(y - x)$$
Note also $f' > 0$, so the left hand side is positive and for $M = f'(1)$ you have 
$$|f(y) - f(x)| < M |y - x|$$
So $f$ is Lipschitz on $[1,\infty)$ which is enough for uniform continuity.