# Show that $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is continous at any $a > 0$

Tags: proof-verification, continuity

We first note that if $|x-a| < \delta$ *and* $\delta \leq 3a$, we have:

$|x-a|<3a \Leftrightarrow -3a < x-a < 3a \Leftrightarrow -2a < x < 4a \Leftrightarrow |x| < 4a \Leftrightarrow |\sqrt{x}| < 2\sqrt{a} $.

Let's also note that $|2\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{a}| \leq |\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{a}| $ and so, $ \frac{1}{|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{a}|} \leq \frac{1}{|2\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{a}|} $.

Then, for all $ \varepsilon > 0 $ there exists $\delta = \min\{ 3a, \sqrt{a}\varepsilon \}$, if $|x-a|<\delta$:

\begin{align}
|f(x) - f(a)| &= |\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{a}| \\
&= \frac{|x-a|}{|\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{a}|} \\
&\leq \frac{|x-a|}{|2\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{a}|} \\
&=\frac{|x-a|}{\sqrt{a}} \\
&< \frac{\delta}{\sqrt{a}} \leq \frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{a}}\varepsilon = \varepsilon
\qquad \text{Q.E.D.}
\end{align}

> Is this proof correct?

Comment: $|\sqrt{x}|\leq |x|$ in your third line is not correct.  Consider $x=0.5$. (btw it is a nice work, just a tiny loophole)

Comment: Possible duplicate of $\downarrow$ and $\longrightarrow$ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1568575/show-fx-sqrtx-is-uniformly-continuous-on-0-infty?rq=1 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569928/sqrt-x-is-uniformly-continuous?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: And we can't conclude $|\sqrt x| < 4a$.  Wat if $a = \frac  1{63}$ and $x = \frac 1{64}$.  Then $\sqrt x =\frac 18 > \frac 4{63}$.  I really doubt $\delta$ should have anything to do with $a$.

Comment: Technically what I am saying is that *if* |x-a| < 3a then |x|<4a.

Answer (score 1):

If $x > 0$
and $h > 0$
then

$\begin{array}\\
|\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x}|
&=|(\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x})\dfrac{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}}|\\
&=|\dfrac{h}{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}}|\\
&\lt|\dfrac{h}{2\sqrt{x}}|\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore,
if
$h < 2\epsilon \sqrt{x}$
then
$|\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x}|
\lt \epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you, Marty, I performed some changes based on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

$|\sqrt x| \le |x| < 4a$ is not true if $x < 1$.

And thus $|\sqrt{x}| \le 4a$ need not be true. If $x < 1$ then $x < \sqrt{x}$ so if $\frac x4 < a < \frac{\sqrt a}4$ this will not be true.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, fleablood. I actually changed big portions of the proof thanks to the error that you pointed out.