# $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow [0,\infty )$ is continuous such that $g(x)={(f(x))}^2$ is uniformly continuous .

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity

$f:\mathbb R\rightarrow [0,\infty )$ is continuous such   that  $g(x)={(f(x))}^2$   is  uniformly continuous . Then which of the following is *always true* $?$

$A.$ $f$ is bounded.

$B.$ $f$ may not be uniformly continuous.

$C.$ $f$ is uniformly continuous.

$D.$ $f$ is unbounded.

I ticked option $C.$  Following is  my  logic **:**

$$f:\mathbb R\rightarrow [0,\infty)$$
$$h:[0,\infty)\rightarrow [0,\infty) ; h(x)=x^2$$
Then $$g=h\circ f$$
Now the function $h$ is bijective(*no* $?$) and $$h^{-1}(x)=\sqrt x$$
So composing  both sides with $h^{-1}$ we get $$f=h^{-1}\circ g$$

Also  both $g$ and $h^{-1}$ being uniformly continuous , $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Was I correct $?$

Also , if my proof  was  correct  I  could  really  use  some  help  to  find  counterexamples  for  the  rest  or  say , why they cannot  be  true .

Thank  you .

Comment: $h$ is not bijective, but that's not the big issue here. The function $x\mapsto\sqrt{x}$ is actually not uniformly continuous on any closed interval containing $0$. So, if $f(x) = \sqrt{|x|}$, then $g(x) = |x|$ is uniformly continuous, but $f$ is not.

Comment: @JoeyZou : Sorry I might be confused here . The function $x\mapsto \sqrt x$  is  continuous  and any closed  interval on $\mathbb R$ , whether contains $0$ or not , is compact. And *continuous functions on compact sets are uniformly continuous* right $?$   Also , this link http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569928/sqrt-x-is-uniformly-continuous  .  And is not   ***positive*** square root of a positive number  ***unique*** $?$

Comment: I was thinking of Lipschitz continuity and not uniform continuity. My bad. Now that I've reread your question, I think everything is ok.

Comment: @joey Zou why $h$ is not bijective ??? it's domain and range is $\mathbb{R}^+$

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is bounded, as if there were a sequence $\{x_n\}$ with $$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n= \lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=\infty,$$
then we would have $\lim_{n\to\infty}f^2(x_n)=\infty$, which contradicts the assumption that $f^2$ converges uniformly on $\mathbb R$. Hence there exists $M$ so that $\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|f(x)|<M$. Let $\varepsilon>0$. Then we may choose $\delta>0$ so that $|x-y|<\delta$ implies $$|f(x)-f(y)|<\frac\varepsilon{2M}\left|f^2(x)-f^2(y)\right|, $$
which yields
$$|f(x)-f(y)| = \frac{\left|f^2(x)-f^2(y)\right|}{|f(x)+f(y)|}<\varepsilon. $$
It follows that $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: does unboundedness of any continuous function on an unbounded interval means that the function is not uniformly continuous?.... you can consider  $g(x)= log(x)$  defined on $[1,\infty)$...