# Uniform Continuity of $\sqrt{x}$ over $(0, \infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

As part of a question of several parts I  have proved the following:

1) that every Lipshitz function is uniformly continuous.

2) that every function that is differentiable and whose derivative is bounded, is Lipshitz.

3)Considering the function $g: [1, \infty) ~~; ~~g(x) = \sqrt{x} $, I have proved that it is uniformly continuous by first proving that it's differentiable and that $g'(x)$ is bounded, therefore it is Lipshitz, and therefore, it is uniformly continuous.

The last part is where i'm stuck on. if we changed g so that $g: (0, \infty)$ then is it uniformly continuous? I have showed that it is unbounded, but I don't know if that means anything.

i'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you familiar with Heine-Cantor theorem?

Comment: not really, sorry

Comment: I've looked it up, yes I know this! but (0, inf) is not compact, so it doesn't hold. am I wrong?

Comment: If a function is uniformly continuous on $A$ and on $B$ then it is uniformly continuous on $A \cup B$. (Just take your $\delta$ that works on $A \cup B$ to be $\min \{ \delta_A,\delta_B \}$.) Accordingly, you can prove that $\sqrt{x}$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$ using any method (Heine-Cantor would be the easiest), and then you can show it is uniformly continuous on $(1,\infty)$ by showing it is Lipschitz there.

Comment: But $[0,2]$ is compact.

Comment: but the set is open at 0, doesn't that make a difference?

Comment: Nope; if a function is uniformly continuous on $A$ and $B \subseteq A$ then it is uniformly continuous on $B$. (Just reuse the same $\delta$.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any continuous function over a compact (ie. closed, bounded) interval is uniformly continuous ([Heine Cantor theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Cantor_theorem)). Therefore the function is uniformly continuous over $[0,1]$. Deriving the result for $[0, +\infty[$ is then easy given what you've already proved.

Comment: thank you but I need the result over ]0,+∞[

Comment: @HexaFlexagon Maybe [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569928/sqrt-x-is-uniformly-continuous) can help you

Answer (score 0):

You can also use that the function is Hölder continuous, for if $0\le x\le y$ one has that
\begin{align}
\sqrt{y}-\sqrt{x}&=\sqrt{x+(y-x)}-\sqrt{x}
\\
&\le\sqrt{x+2\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y-x}+(y-x)}
\\
&=(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y-x})-\sqrt{x}=\sqrt{y-x}
\end{align}
so that in general
$$
|\sqrt{y}-\sqrt{x}|\le\sqrt{|y-x|}
$$
which is Hölder with index $1/2$ and thus uniformly continuous on $[0\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

On $[1,+\infty [$, using mean value theorem, $|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt y|=|x-y|$ and thus is uniform continuous. On $[0,1]$, the uniform continuity is obvious (continuous function on a compact). Now, if $x\leq 1\leq y$, you have that $$|\sqrt x-\sqrt y|\leq |\sqrt x-\sqrt 1|+|\sqrt y-\sqrt 1|,$$
and thus, the claim almost follow using previous results.