# Is $1 / \sqrt{x}$ Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

If $\int_0^1 1 / \sqrt{x}\,\mathrm dx$ Riemann integrable then using second fundamental theorem of calculus I can easily say that $\sqrt{x}$ is uniformly continuous.

Basically it has one point i.e. $0$ where it diverges. Otherwise I can use the theorem that a function with finite number of discontinuous points is Riemann integrable. Can I take zero as point of discontinuity?

Comment: Is $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ bounded at $x=0$?

Comment: $\sqrt x$ is continuous on the compact interval $[0, 1]$ – that already implies uniform continuity on the interval. You don't need an integral for that argument.

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{x}$ is uniformly continuous on all of $\mathbb{R}^{+}$.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569928/sqrt-x-is-uniformly-continuous

Comment: Looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) ...

Comment: @MartinR No .X was my main problem i just stated Y (Y can be solved by this way also )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That function is unbounded (whatever way you choose it to extend it to $0$), and therefore it is *not* Riemann-integrable (*by definition*, every Riemann-integrable function is bounded). However, the improper integral $\int_0^1\frac1{\sqrt x}\,\mathrm dx$ converges.

The theorem that you mentioned holds for *bounded* functions, not in general.

Comment: This means when we talk about Riemann integrable functions we mean that it has to be bounded ? in other words we consider only bounded functions in study of Riemann integration ?

Comment: **Yes**, you are absolutely right.

Comment: Also one more doubt - suppose a function is unbounded at  a point ( like the function in this question is unbounded at $0$ ) then can we say the function is discontinuous at that point ? (This doubt is irrelevant to this question)

Comment: Yes, that is correct. To be more precise: if $a$ belongs to the domain $D_f$ of $f$ and if, for each $r>0$, the restriction of $f$ to $(a-r,a+r)\cap D_f$ is unbounded, then $f$ is discontinuous at $a$.

Comment: @Upstart Yes, I mean what I say: the **improper** integral $\int_0^1\frac1{\sqrt x}\,\mathrm dx$ converges, since\begin{align}\int_0^1\frac1{\sqrt x}\,\mathrm dx&=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\int_\varepsilon^1\frac1{\sqrt x}\,\mathrm dx\\&=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\left(2-2\sqrt\varepsilon\right)\\&=2.\end{align}

Comment: No No, what I was trying to ask here is given the OP's question if we add the part that $f(x)=0$ for $x=0$, then also it is unbounded since given any bound $M$ we can always find an $x=\frac{1}{(M+1)^2}$ which violates the condition of boundedness. Which is what you wanted to say I guess. To make it short even if we define like this even the the function is bounded.

Comment: I wrote in my answer that “That function is unbounded (whatever way you choose it to extend it to $0$)”.

Comment: Yes you are right, after my comment, I thought over your answer, and found my reasoning flawed.

Comment: +1 for the answer and more importantly for the nice discussion in comments.

Comment: If that function is not *Riemann integrable* then *what* kind of integrability method is that?

Comment: @William It's an *improper* integral. Did you read the comments?

Comment: Just did and I looked it up. From what I understand, it's not a *method* of integration. It's more of a *type* of integral that is extended from a method of integration (like Riemann method or Lebesgue method etc), am I on the right track?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The function is unbounded, but, for any $\varepsilon\in(0,1)$, its restriction to $[\varepsilon,1]$ *is* bounded. Actually, it is Riemann-integrable. And so we define the improper inter $\int_0^1\frac1{\sqrt x}\,\mathrm dx$ by$$\int_0^1\frac1{\sqrt x}\,\mathrm dx=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\int_\varepsilon^1\frac1{\sqrt x}\,\mathrm dx.$$

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ is not bounded on $(0,1)$, and therefore, it cannot be Riemann integrable.

However, $\sqrt{x}$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and $[0,1]$ is a compact set, therefore, $\sqrt x$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$. Also, the derivative of $\sqrt{x}$ is bounded on $[1, \infty)$, so $\sqrt{x}$ is uniformly continuous on $[1, \infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

It's unbounded so no it's not Riemann integrable. It is improperly Riemann integrable though.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the integrand is unbounded in the domain of integration so it is not Riemann integrable.

The improper integral does exist if it is perrceived as the limit $$\displaystyle\lim_{a\to0^+}\int_a^1\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}=\lim_{a\to0^+}(2-2\sqrt{a})=2$$

Comment: Yadati the function isn't even defined at all points in the domain $[0,1]$ so should any further investigation be done, since it fails the definition of being a function since you have no image of $0$ under $f$.